# C++11 regex matching a full word that does not end with a period?

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am trying to match any full word that does not end with a period. I have the following regex with negative lookahead, `std::regex rex("\\w+(?!\\.)");`

However it is still producing a match on words like `"joe."`  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure the word is followed with a word boundary:

```
std::regex rex(R"(\w+\b(?!\.))");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YS3BMr/1)

Otherwise, backtracking occurs and you find `jo` in `joe.` with [your pattern](https://regex101.com/r/JpOLnm/1).

I also advise to use raw string literals when defining a regex, you get rid of excessive backslashes this way.

Comment: Thanks that works, I will accept your answer in 8 mins :)